# How to finish call phone from my android app?

Tags: android

I have my Android app and I want to to finish call phone from my application.
How I can to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add this file ITelephony.aidl then use this method to end the call:

```
public static void callReject(Context context) throws Exception{
        try{
            TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            Class c = Class.forName(manager.getClass().getName());
            Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
            m.setAccessible(true);
            ITelephony telephony = (ITelephony)m.invoke(manager);
            telephony.endCall();
        } catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("",e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are there some other options? I just don't want to use ITelephony

Comment: NO idea but why you don't want to use ITelephony?